Autocomplete popup in WebStorm has zero height
Hello everyone using developer tools from JetBrains.
For a while now I have problems with the visibility of the popup with the autocomplete:

With very precise mouse positioning I can actually resize it. See image below. In the case ScenarioPartType.Actions there is a gray line above the break-statement. This is the autocomplete popup.

I have looked at a number of other answers but I cannot seem to find the cause nor the solution. Anyone?
UPDATE
Ok, so the problem seemed gone. Sometimes I do get a normal popup, but occasionally the problem returns. I will investigate further!

(it's not the same as yours, but anyway) See if this solution helps -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-31723#focus=Comments-27-9289248.0-0 (do it while the IDE is closed ofc)

Ok. this is very weird: problem disappeared after weeks of frustration although I did nothing... Ok, I updated a plugins (dev-containers) and possibly Wakatime)-plugin.
